# Export XML task results (in task scheduler) to a mongo DB

Tags: xml, mongodb, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a task in task scheduler from an XML file, it works fine.

my question is - how can I export task results to a Mongo DB?

for example I have this task which run ipconfig command:

**

```html
<Actions>
  <Exec>
    <Command>%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</Command>
    <Arguments>ipconfig</Arguments>
  </Exec>
</Actions>
```

**

how can I save the ipconfig results in mongo DB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can save the XML as simple text in MongoDB.

Comment: What do you mean the XML? the XML file is the task and I want to save the task results
Add example to my question